# Resource-based vs. Entity-based structure

Tags: data-structures, microservices

When it comes to designing the architecture of a system and the underlying services (consider a SOA), the database models can be designed it some ways, right... The general one is `entity-based`, which speaks for itself - the business logic is built around the entities (f.e. `user`, `company`, `product`). But when `resource-based` comes in the picture, it gets confusing. And the problem continues when I get results with very abstract or ambiguous information in google.

My focus here is on a CRM service (Customer Relations Management). But I deem it better for me to understand resource-based structure in general, in order to be able to design a service in such a way.

Can someone provide a concise explanation of resource-based structure and maybe compare it with entity-based?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "resource-based," or provide a reference to where you see it discussed as an alternative to the entity-based model.

Comment: @JimMischel, well the fact is that I myself don't really know how to understand "resource-based" structure, that's why I decided to ask for help here. I can't provide a reference. My CTO just told me to design the structure to be "resource-based" instead of "entity-based" and now he's on vacation, so I'm in a dead-end street...

Comment: I could speculate on what "resource-based" means, but it would be just that: pure speculation. You'll have to wait for your boss to get back. Or perhaps somebody else has an idea of what he meant.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the most concise explanation in Fielding's dissertation on REST:

> A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities

If that's the context you were looking for, you can read more [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1)